# Is AutoConfigureAfter inherently conditional?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

The documentation surrounding `@AutoConfigureAfter` doesn't really go into much detail in regards to its conditional nature.

Suppose I have the following classes. And lets assume that `A.class` does exist on the classpath.

`@Configuration
@ConditionalOnMissingClass(A.class)
public class BConfig{
...
}`

`@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(BConfig.class)
public class CConfig{
...
}`

If this is the case would `CConfig` be created and configured if `BConfig` never occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, it would've taken you, like, 5 minutes to test it out. Yes, the CConfig class gets processed even if the condition for BClass is false.